# Flex socket policy only works if I set the domain to *

Tags: apache-flex, sockets, amazon-ec2

I have a Flex application on an in house server that connects to a MongoDB server running on an amazon ec2 instance. Connecting directly from Flex requires me to serve up a socket policy. Below is what I am currently using:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<!-- Policy file for xmlsocket://socks.example.com -->
<cross-domain-policy>

   <!-- This is a master socket policy file -->
   <!-- No other socket policies on the host will be permitted -->
   <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>

   <!-- Instead of setting to-ports="*", administrator's can use ranges and commas -->
   <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="27017" />

</cross-domain-policy>
```

This works fine. My Flex client connects successfully and all is well. However if I change the allow-access-from domain from a * to the Flex server's IP it does not work. I don't think this is a major concern since I have both ports 843 and 27017 only open to the Flex server's IP via the ec2 security group, but I would like to find out why it only works with the wildcard in place if possible.

Comment: Does not work as in, what error do you get?

Comment: The flex client won't connect, eventually times out,  when I specify the domain in the policy file.

Comment: Normally it does not time out, it errors out saying that crossdomain file is required. Did you check with the wireshark and see what response you are getting back? you can also try removing the 'to-ports ' and see if this works.

Comment: I don't get an error when calling .loadPolicyFile, it simply won't connect to mongo in this case. The policyfile server even shows that it sends the policy file to the flex client.

Comment: Taking out the port has no different effect